# Is there a way to init a list without using square bracket in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Is there a way to init a list without using square bracket in Python?

For example, is there a function like `list_cons` so that:

```
x = list_cons(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Judging by the `functional-programming` tag and use of the term `cons`, it would seem the asker is trying to get Python to be as much like Lisp as possible. But then, why not just use Lisp? If for some reason an underlying Python implementation is required (to make use of Python libraries or something), then maybe check out the various Lisp-in-Python implementations [here](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~annis/creations/PyLisp/) (the linked page has further links to other implementations).

Comment: A Python list is not a cons/linked list, it's an array, so if you think you want this, you've probably mislead yourself badly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [1]: def list_cons(*args):
   ...:     return list(args)
   ...: 

In [2]: list_cons(1,2,3,4)
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why not just directly use the list method?

Comment: Not completely sure why the asker asked this question, but this answer clearly matches the sought-after syntax, and is thus almost certainly the best answer for the asker's needs.

Comment: @Dhara so he doesnt have to pass it a tuple. list(1,2,3) raises TypeError. list_cons(1,2,3) works

Comment: @Dhara: Because `list()` takes at most 1 argument.

Comment: Thanks @JohnY, I was typing the same... except for the "best" part :)

Comment: I guess my quarrel was with the question, not your answer. It seems fairly pointless to wrap the list call in a function just to avoid typing brackets

Answer (score 6):

Use the list constructor and pass it a tuple.

```
x = list((1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: You could even do: `x = list([1,2,3,4])`. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that would be a particularly useful function. Is typing brackets so hard? Perhaps we could give you a more useful answer if you explained why you want this.

Still, here's a fun thing you can do in Python 3:

```
>>> (*x,) = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can even omit the parenthesis -- `*x, = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` works too.

Comment: Didn't know of that yet, so +1. But I hope I'll never stumble upon this in production code ;-)

Comment: Why does it make a list and not any other iterable?

Comment: @Dhara, the short answer is "[because](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)." Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/getting-python-sequence-assignments-unpacking-right) for more corner cases.

Comment: @Dhara, less flippantly, the PEP I linked to says that using a tuple (and presumably any other type of iterable) would "make further processing of the result harder." (See the [third bullet point](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#acceptance).)

Answer (score 1):

works only in **python 2.x**:

```
>>> def list_cons(*args):
       return map(None,args)

>>> list_cons(1,2,3,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```