# Determining the number of return values in a Python function

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-decorators

I am creating a decorator that catches a raised error in it's target function, and allows the user to continue executing the script (bypassing the function) or drop out of the script.

```
def catch_error(func):
    """
    This decorator is used to make sure that if a decorated function breaks 
    in the execution of a script, the script doesn't automatically crash. 
    Instead, it gives you the choice to continue or gracefully exit.    

    """
    def caught(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except Exception as err:
            question = '\n{0} failed. Continue? (yes/no): '.format(func.func_name)
            answer = raw_input(question)
            if answer.lower() in ['yes','y']:
                pass
            else:
                print "   Aborting! Error that caused failure:\n"
                raise err 
            return None
    return caught
```

Notice that, if the user chooses to bypass the error-returning function and continue executing the script, the decorator returns None. This works well for functions that only return a single value, but it is crashing on functions that attempt to unpack multiple values. For instance,

```
# Both function and decorator return single value, so works fine
one_val = decorator_works_for_this_func() 
# Function nominally returns two values, but decorator only one, so this breaks script
one_val, two_val = decorator_doesnt_work_for_this_func()
```

Is there a way that I can determine the number of values my target function is supposed to return? For instance, something like:

```
def better_catch_error(func):
    def caught(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except Exception as err:
            ...
            num_rvals = determine_num_rvals(func)
            if num_rvals > 1:
                return [ None for count in range(num_rvals) ]
            else:
                return None               
    return caught
```

As always, if there is a better way to do this sort of thing, please let me know. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the suggestions. I decided to narrow the scope of catch_error to a single class of functions, which only return one string value. I just split all the functions returning more than one value into separate functions that return a single value to make them compatible. I had been hoping to make catch_error more generic (and there were several helpful suggestions on how to do that), but for my application it was a little overkill. Thanks again.

Comment: Nit: Only *one* value may be returned (or returned at a time with a generator). In the case of `a,b=f(..)` it just happens to be (or not be in the None case) returning a tuple (or [something else that can be unpacked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/getting-python-sequence-assignments-unpacking-right).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martijn Pieters answer is correct, this is a specific case of [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

However you might get around it by passing a error return value to the decorator. Something like this:

```
def catch_error(err_val):
    def wrapper(func):
        def caught(*args):
            try:
                return func(*args)
            except Exception as err:
                question = '\n{0} failed. Continue? (yes/no): '.format(func.func_name)
                answer = raw_input(question)
                if answer.lower() in ['yes','y']:
                    pass
                else:
                    print "   Aborting! Error that caused failure:\n"
                    raise err 
                return err_val
        return caught
    return wrapper
```

Then you could decorate using:

```
@catch_error({})
def returns_a_dict(*args, **kwargs):
    return {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
```

Also as a point of style, if you are grabbing `*args` in your wrapped function, you should probably also grab `**kwargs` so that you can properly wrap functions that take keyword arguments. Otherwise your wrapped function will fail if you call `wrapped_function(something=value)`

Finally, as another point of style, it is confusing to see code that does `if a: pass` with an else. Try using `if !a` in these cases. So the final code:

```
def catch_error(err_val):
    def wrapper(func):
        def caught(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as err:
                question = '\n{0} failed. Continue? (yes/no): '.format(func.func_name)
                answer = raw_input(question)
                if answer.lower() not in ['yes','y']:
                    print "   Aborting! Error that caused failure:\n"
                    raise err
                return err_val
        return caught
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way you can determine that.

Python is a dynamic language, and a given function can return an arbitrary sequence of any size or no sequence at all, based on the inputs and other factors.

For example:

```
import random

def foo():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return ('spam', 'eggs')
    return None
```

This function will return a tuple half of the time, but `None` the other half, so Python has no way of telling you what `foo()` will return.

There are many more ways your decorator can fail, btw, not just when the function returns a sequence that the caller then unpacks. What if the caller expected a dictionary and starts trying to access keys, or a list and wants to know the length?

Answer (score 3):

Your decorator can't predict what your function is going to return, but nothing prevents you from *telling* the decorator what return signature to simulate:

```
@catch_error([None, None])
def tuple_returner(n):
    raise Exception
    return [2, 3]
```

Instead of returning `None`, your decorator will return its argument (`[None, None]`).

Writing an argument-taking decorator is just slightly tricky: The expression `catch_error([None, None])` will be evaluated, and must return the actual decorator that will be applied to the decorated function. It looks like this:

```
def catch_error(signature=None):
    def _decorator(func):
        def caught(*args):
            try:
                return func(*args)
            except Exception as err:
                # Interactive code suppressed
                return signature

        return caught

    return _decorator
```

Note that even if you just want it to return `None`, you need to execute it once:

```
@catch_error()
def some_function(x):
    ...
```