# Print range of numbers on same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python I want to print a range of numbers on the same line. how can I do this using python, I can do it using C by not adding `\n`, but how can I do it using python.

```
for x in xrange(1,10):
    print x
```

I am trying to get this result.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Python 2

```
for x in xrange(1,11):
    print x,
```

Python 3

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print(x, end=" ")
```

Comment: That is a very simple solution! But what are the differences between this and the more complex solutions that others gave?  answer accepted!

Comment: So, "print x," is just the short hand way of escaping the newline when you're doing a series of prints. Your print was in a for loop, so this made sense. Below, the string.join method takes an iterable and combines each element with the supplied string and returns a single string. So instead of multiple prints without newlines, you're doing one print with a newline; just pre compiling all your printable elements into one string.

Answer (score 79):

```
>>>print(*range(1,11)) 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Python one liner to print the range

Comment: Great answer. What's actually the meaning of the `*`?

Comment: @majom `*` unpacks the sequence.

Comment: Thanks. That I understood. Are you aware of a link to the documentation of `*`? It is hard to google for that.

Comment: There are a few threads on the usage of `*`. You can very well refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking)

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end = ' ')
```

You can provide any delimiter to the end field (space, comma etc.)

This is for Python 3

Answer (score 9):

`str.join` would be appropriate in this case

```
>>> print ' '.join(str(x) for x in xrange(1,11))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, `xrange` is not supported in Python3.

You can try -

```
print(*range(1,11))
```

OR

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end = ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Same can be achieved by using `stdout`.

```
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> for i in range(1,11):
...     stdout.write(str(i)+' ')
...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Alternatively, same can be done by using `reduce()` :

```
>>> xrange = range(1,11)
>>> print reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + ' '+str(y), xrange)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>>>
```

Comment: so much complexity for such a simple question. Plus, neither of those escape a new line, your first is piping to stdout which needs to be imported from sys and your second is concatenating strings with a lambda and an overwritten reserved function. Why wouldn't you use ' '.join(<list>)?? Both of these are bad practice.

Comment: @BlakeVandeMerwe I am trying to cover the possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
[print(i, end = ' ') for i in range(10)]
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is a list comprehension method of answer same as @Anubhav

Comment: This needlessly creates a list

Comment: In Python 3, better to use the unpacked list inside the print:

`print(*[i for i in range(10)], sep=" ")`

This way avoiding the creation of the empty list mentioned by @OneCricketeer

Comment: @AldoBassanini That creates a list as well... You also don't need `i for i in`. Just `print(*range(10))`

Comment: @OneCricketeer the `range` object doesn't create an internal list when unpacked?

Comment: @AldoBassanini It is a generator in Python3

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i)
```

i know this is an old question but i think this works now

Comment: No, it doesn't! Both the Python 3 print function and the Python 2 print statement implicitly adds a newline by default.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer has been given for the question. I would like to add, if in case we need to print numbers without any spaces then we can use the following code

```
        for i in range(1,n):
            print(i,end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another single-line Python 3 option but with explicit separator:

`print(*range(1,11), sep=' ')`

Comment: Can you please explain how does it work, 
What is that * before range.

Comment: @VijenderKumar This will print 1 to 10, separated by whatever string you put in the sep attribute.  In the example above, each integer string is separated by a space.

Comment: @VijenderKumar that's just python parameter positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(i,end='')
```

Comment: Why is this better than the accepted answer, or different from the answer that suggest exactly this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `end = " "`, inside the print function

Code:

```
for x in range(1,11):
       print(x,end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3:

```
for i in range(1,10): 
    print(i,end='')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that can handle x with single or multiple rows like scipy pdf:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn

# covariance matrix
sigma = np.array([[2.3, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1.5, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1.7, 0],
           [0, 0,   0, 2]
          ])
# mean vector
mu = np.array([2,3,8,10])

# input
x1 = np.array([2.1, 3.5, 8., 9.5])
x2 = np.array([[2.1, 3.5, 8., 9.5],[2.2, 3.6, 8.1, 9.6]])


def multivariate_normal_pdf(x, mu, cov):
    x_m = x - mu

    if x.ndim > 1:
        sum_ax = 1
        t_ax = [0] 
        t_ax.extend(list(range(x_m.ndim)[:0:-1])) # transpose dims > 0
    else:
        sum_ax = 0
        t_ax = range(x_m.ndim)[::-1]


    x_m_t = np.transpose(x_m, axes=t_ax) 
    A = 1 / ( ((2* np.pi)**(len(mu)/2)) * (np.linalg.det(cov)**(1/2)) )
    B = (-1/2) * np.sum(x_m_t.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov)) * x_m,axis=sum_ax)
    return A * np.exp(B)

print(mvn.pdf(x1, mu, sigma))
print(multivariate_normal_pdf(x1, mu, sigma))

print(mvn.pdf(x2, mu, sigma))
print(multivariate_normal_pdf(x2, mu, sigma))
```