# Why is a loop required to print all the numbers generated by the range function in python?

Tags: python

If `range(0, 3)` returns the sequence 0, 1, 2

then why can't I simply print this sequence using the following code:

```
x = range (0, 3)
print(x)
```

Why do I need to use a `for loop` to do so?

```
x = range (0, 3)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

How do I understand how the `range` function generates the sequence and stores it, making a iterating function necessary to access all the numbers in the sequence.

Comment: Might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464225/9374673) as well about printing ranges. Doesn't quite answer this specific question but worth having a look.

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely beacause `range` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators); it doesn't return a list, it returns an iterable object whose `next()` method returns another item from the list it represents.

Of course, you can always

```py
print(list(range(0, 3))
```

or

```py
print(*range(0, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` is a generator function not a list. To get values from a generator you need to iterate through the generator calling for the next value. A for loop does that.

Answer (score 1):

`range(0, 3)` is a generator so the values are not actually produced until you loop over it.

You could cast it to a list to print:

```
x = range(0, 3)
print(list(x))
```