# Python string get leading characters up to first comma

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
strIn = "Head,0.000235532,0.43656735"
```

I would like to retrieve from this a variable `type = "Head"` and an array 
`vals = [0.000235532,0.43656735]`

How can I do this using Python? I've considered using strIn[0],...,strIn[5] to get the type, but then I realized I'll get types of various lengths. Thanks.

Comment: `str.split` would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, you can do

```
type_, *vals = strIn.split(',')
vals = [float(v) for v in vals]  # Convert list of strings to list of floats.
```

This uses [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the string into a list based on the provided character, and then uses Python 3's extended tuple unpacking to put the first value into `type_` and the remaining values into `vals`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking) for more discussion on how to use tuple unpacking.

If you're on Python 2 you can't use the extended unpacking syntax, so you have to add an additional step:

```
str_list = strIn.split(',')
type_ = str_list[0]
vals = [float(v) for v in str_list[1:]]
```

Comment: Note that ``*vals`` will be a list of strings.

Comment: @Menegazzo True. I added a line to convert it to a list of floats.

Comment: @jds I think it will work on Python 2.7 as well. Just give it a try.

Comment: @jds Added a version for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

As you are in python2 first split with `,` then use slicing and `float` function :

```
>>> none=strIn.split(',')[0]
>>> none
'Head'
>>> vals=map(float,strIn.split(',')[1:])
>>> vals
[0.000235532, 0.43656735]
```

As `type` is a built-in name recommended that dont use it !

Comment: `type` is a special keyword, that code could have surprising consequences ;-)