# How do I recursively increment the first value in a list and append to a nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I wrote a function called `change` which takes in an `int` and a list of coins.

It recursively checks what the least amount of coins are needed to create that amount and returns this number. Now I am trying to modify this function to take the same input but instead return a list with the number of coins and a list of coins used.

```
def change(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        return 0
    if coins == []:
        return float("inf")
    if coins[0] > amount:
        return change(amount, coins[1:])
    use_it = 1+change(amount-coins[0], coins)
    lose_it = change(amount, coins[1:])
    return min(use_it, lose_it)
```

I began modifying this code but I'm not sure how to manipulate the return value given that it's a list:

```
def giveChange(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        return [0, []]
    if coins == []:
        return [float("inf"), []]
    if coins[0] > amount:
        return giveChange(amount, coins[1:])
    use_it = 1 + giveChange(amount-coins[0], coins)
    lose_it = giveChange(amount, coins[1:])
    listOfCoins = 
    return [min(use_it, lose_it), listOfCoins]
```

I have this so far but my use_it line is wrong because the function now returns a list. Could I simply do this:

```
use_it = 1 + giveChange(amount-coins[0], coins)[0]
```

I am not sure how to build up the list of coins so that I can return it with the amount of coins at the end.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your programming question is, but perhaps you need to research [unpacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking).

Comment: You may want to update your question title, it doesn't really reflect what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> return a list with the number of coins and a list of coins used.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def giveChange(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        return [0, []]
    if coins == []:
        return [float("inf"), []]
    if coins[0] > amount:
        return giveChange(amount, coins[1:])
    [use_it_amt, use_it_list] = giveChange(amount-coins[0], coins)
    [lose_it_amt, lose_it_list] = giveChange(amount, coins[1:])
    if use_it_amt+1 < lose_it_amt:
        use_it_list.append(coins[0])
        return [use_it_amt+1, use_it_list]
    else:
        return [lose_it_amt, lose_it_list]
```

Here you can see it working: https://repl.it/Bn2T

As this is Dynamic Programming something good would be to use a memoization table to prevent the recalculation of sub problems, furthermore it is stack dependent and will give you StackOverflow if the quantity of recursion calls is too large.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for! The only issue I found was that `lose_it_list.append(coins[0])` at the end was unnecessary because it was appending coins that were not being used.

Answer (score 1):

Just handle the second parameter correctly throughout your code, the only difficult is `use_it` needs to add 1 to the number of coins and add the `coin[0]` to the list of coins used. `min` will need to take in account and key on the first parameter:

```
def give_change(amount, coins):
    if amount == 0:
        return [0, []]
    if coins == []:
        return [float('inf'), []]
    if coins[0] > amount:
        return give_change(amount, coins[1:])
    use_it = [x+y for x,y in zip(give_change(amount-coins[0], coins), [1,[coins[0]]])]
    lose_it = give_change(amount, coins[1:])
    return min(use_it, lose_it, key=lambda x: x[0])

>>> give_change(53, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100])
[3, [50, 2, 1]]
```

Taking a more dynamic programming approach to this you can do it without recursion. I've assumed you can reuse the coins (as your original code also reused coins). `give_change` now returns all the ways you can achieve the amount with the coins, which you can just `min` with a `key=len`:

```
def give_change(amount, coins):
    ways = [list() for _ in range(0, amount+1)]
    ways[0].append([])

    for coin in coins:
        for i, x in enumerate(range(coin, amount+1)):
            ways[x].extend(l+[coin] for l in ways[i])
    return ways[amount]

>>> give_change(3, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100])
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2]]
>>> min(give_change(3, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]), key=len)
[1, 2]
>>> min(give_change(53, [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]), key=len)
[1, 2, 50]
```