# Finds all rows fitting to combinatorial condition

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas, google-sheets

I'm looking for the best way to do this using python\excel\sql\google sheets - 
I need to find all rows which fits to k values from list of n values.

For example I have this table called Animals:

```
| Name     | mammal | move   |  dive |
+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| Giraffe  |  1     |    1   |   0   |
| Frog     |  0     |    1   |   1   |
| Dolphin  |  1     |    1   |   1   |
| Snail    |  0     |    1   |   0   | 
| Bacteria |  0     |    0   |   0   |
```

And I want to write a function foo that do behave like that:

> foo(tuple of Boolean values, minimum matches)

```
foo((1,1,1),3) -> Dolphin
foo((1,1,1),2) -> Giraffe, Dolphin, Frog
foo((1,1,1),1) -> Giraffe, Dolphin, Frog, Snail
foo((1,1,0),2) -> Giraffe, Dolphin
foo((0,1,1),2) -> Dolphin, Frog
foo((0,1,1),1) -> Giraffe, Dolphin, Frog, Snail
foo((1,1,1),0) -> Giraffe, Dolphin, Frog, Snail, Bacteria
```

What's the best way you think about?

Comment: sql not in ('python', 'excel', 'google sheets')

Comment: I fixed it, sql is great as well

Comment: How is foo((1,1,0),2)  only Giraffe, Dolphin? Wouldn't there be snail?

Comment: foo((1,1,0),2) looking for all mammal and move

Comment: Only Dolphin and Frog move and dive –  this is reply for foo((0,1,1),2) -> Dolphin, Frog, but both dolphin & snail is 1.not a mammal and snail can 2.move.  2 matches.

Comment: move and dive is ((0,1,1),2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pure Python 3 solution.

```
data = [
    ('Giraffe',  1, 1, 0),
    ('Frog',     0, 1, 1),
    ('Dolphin',  1, 1, 1),
    ('Snail',    0, 1, 0),
    ('Bacteria', 0, 0, 0),
]

probes = [
    ((1, 1, 1), 3),
    ((1, 1, 1), 2),
    ((1, 1, 1), 1),
    ((1, 1, 0), 2),
    ((0, 1, 1), 2),
    ((0, 1, 1), 1),
    ((1, 1, 1), 0),
]

def foo(mask, minmatch):
    for name, *row in data:
        if sum(u & v for u, v in zip(mask, row)) >= minmatch:
            yield name

for mask, minmatch in probes:
    print(mask, minmatch, *foo(mask, minmatch))
```

**output**

```
(1, 1, 1) 3 Dolphin
(1, 1, 1) 2 Giraffe Frog Dolphin
(1, 1, 1) 1 Giraffe Frog Dolphin Snail
(1, 1, 0) 2 Giraffe Dolphin
(0, 1, 1) 2 Frog Dolphin
(0, 1, 1) 1 Giraffe Frog Dolphin Snail
(1, 1, 1) 0 Giraffe Frog Dolphin Snail Bacteria
```

Tested on Python 3.6.0. It uses some syntax that's not available in older versions, but it's easy to adapt it to use older syntax.

---

This variation runs on older versions of Python. Tested on Python 2.6.6.

```
from __future__ import print_function

data = [
    ('Giraffe',  1, 1, 0),
    ('Frog',     0, 1, 1),
    ('Dolphin',  1, 1, 1),
    ('Snail',    0, 1, 0),
    ('Bacteria', 0, 0, 0),
]

probes = [
    ((1, 1, 1), 3),
    ((1, 1, 1), 2),
    ((1, 1, 1), 1),
    ((1, 1, 0), 2),
    ((0, 1, 1), 2),
    ((0, 1, 1), 1),
    ((1, 1, 1), 0),
]

def foo(mask, minmatch):
    for row in data:
        if sum(u & v for u, v in zip(mask, row[1:])) >= minmatch:
            yield row[0]

for mask, minmatch in probes:
    matches = list(foo(mask, minmatch))
    print(mask, minmatch, matches)
```

**output**

```
(1, 1, 1) 3 ['Dolphin']
(1, 1, 1) 2 ['Giraffe', 'Frog', 'Dolphin']
(1, 1, 1) 1 ['Giraffe', 'Frog', 'Dolphin', 'Snail']
(1, 1, 0) 2 ['Giraffe', 'Dolphin']
(0, 1, 1) 2 ['Frog', 'Dolphin']
(0, 1, 1) 1 ['Giraffe', 'Frog', 'Dolphin', 'Snail']
(1, 1, 1) 0 ['Giraffe', 'Frog', 'Dolphin', 'Snail', 'Bacteria']
```

Comment: @SuperMario It's fairly new syntax that's only available in recent versions of Python. Basically, `name, *row` splits the current `data` tuple so the 1st tuple item gets assigned to `name` and the rest of the tuple gets assigned to `row`. Here's a simpler example: `a, *b = (1,2,3)` puts `1` into `a` and `(2,3)` into `b`. Similarly, `*a, b=(4,5,6)` puts `(4,5)` into `a` and `6` into `b`.

Comment: is it has a name?

Comment: @SuperMario Yes. :) It's called [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#acceptance). It is mentioned on [this Stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6967632/4014959), with lots of other variations of tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to use python with pandas

assume "Name" column is pandas index:

```
def foo(df, bool_index, minimum_matches):
    picked_column_index = [ idx for (idx, i) in enumerate(bool_index) if i] # select where "1" is
    picked_df = df.iloc[:, picked_column_index] #select column by location
    matched_row_bool = picked_df.sum(axis=1) >= minimum_matches
    return picked_df[matched_row_bool].index.tolist()
```

df is a pandas dataframe read from the table (Animals)
maybe:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('animials_csv_file_path')
```

or

```
df = pandas.read_excel('animials_xls_file_path')
```

It will return a list include matched name

Comment: what is df in this function?

Answer (score 1):

If the table is a pandas dataframe:

```
def foo(df, val, n_match):
    results = []
    for r in  df.values:
        if sum(val & r[1:]) >= n_match:
            results.append(r[0])
    print("foo(%s), %d -> %s") % (val, n_match, ' '.join(results))
```