# Why does *x, unpack map objects in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

In Python 3, the following returns a map object:

```
map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
```

If we want to turn this object into a list, we can just cast it as a list using `list(mapobject)`. However, I discovered through code golfing that

```
*x, = mapobject
```

makes x into a list. Why is this allowed in Python 3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking duplicate?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga IMO the proposed duplicate is more of a rant than a genuine question (if it were written today, I'd vote to close it as primarily opinion based). While the accepted answer is good, and does mention the `*x, = iterable` syntax, I don't think someone else looking for an answer to Sandeep's question would find it as easily there as here. Thanks for not immediately hammering it, anyway ... I'll take this to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and see what a larger group thinks.

Answer (score 9):

This is an example of extended iterable unpacking, introduced into Python 3 by [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

> This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not assigned to a "regular" name.
>
> An example says more than a thousand words:
>
> ```
> >>> a, *b, c = range(5)
> >>> a
> 0
> >>> c
> 4
> >>> b
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

As usual in Python, singleton tuples are expressed using a trailing comma, so that the extended equivalent of this:

```
>>> x, = [1]
>>> x
1
```

… is this:

```
>>> *x, = range(3)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2]
```