# How to unpack a nested list in Python3?

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

```
Lst = [[1,2,3],[201,202,203],[3,1,4],[591,2019,3.14]]
```

What I need is-

```
a1,b1,c1 = (1,2,3)

a2,b2,c2 = (201,202,203)
```

and so on ...

Comment: Related: [python - Unpacking, extended unpacking, and nested extended unpacking - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking)

Answer (score 3):

You are a looking to map values to coordinates. Well, you *can* just access directly via `L[outer_list_idx][inner_list_idx]` with a couple of list operations.

#### For non-numeric indexing, use dict

You can use a dictionary for a variable number of variables. This removes the need to define a large number of variables explicitly.

Using letters has the obvious limitation of allowing a maximum of 26 lists. If this is what you wish, there's no need to define letters explicitly, use `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

L = [[1,2,3],[201,202,203],[3,1,4],[591,2019,3.14]]

m, n = len(L), len(L[0])

d = {(ascii_lowercase[j], i+1): L[i][j] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)}

print(d)

{('a', 1): 1, ('b', 1): 2, ('c', 1): 3,
 ('a', 2): 201, ('b', 2): 202, ('c', 2): 203,
 ('a', 3): 3, ('b', 3): 1, ('c', 3): 4,
 ('a', 4): 591, ('b', 4): 2019, ('c', 4): 3.14}
```

Then access via tuple keys. So, to retrieve the 2nd value from the 3rd list, you can use `d[('b', 3)]`.

Comment: I suppose that you're thinking that OP has an XY problem and try to solve the X.

Comment: You probably meant "downvoting a **good** answer for a bad question". Although if it's a duplicate, people should just answer the duplicate target.

Comment: My example wasn't the *best* because I use numeric coordinates. You can, fairly easily, also use `a` instead of `1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The example is can be solved with simple tuple unpacking. You can use `zip` to pair your values:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[201,202,203],[3,1,4],[591,2019,3.14]]

((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)), _ = zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])
print(a1, b1, c1)
print(a2, b2, c2)
```

This will print:

```
1 2 3
201 202 203
```

If you want next values, you can do:

```
_, ((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)) = zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])
print(a1, b1, c1)
print(a2, b2, c2)
```

Output:

```
3 1 4
591 2019 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for this:

```
t = [[1,2,3],[201,202,203],[3,1,4],[591,2019,3.14]]

from itertools import chain 
a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4 = chain.from_iterable(t) # flattens the list of lists

print(a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4)
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3 201 202 203 3 1 4 591 2019 3.14
```

You need to know the dimensions of the list beforehand and the variablenames. I would probably just use the original list ...

Comment: Thanks @jpp - no idea why/who dv but I'd rather have constructive feedback with a dv as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need the values? Then like that:

```
Lst = [[1,2,3],[201,202,203],[3,1,4],[591,2019,3.14]]

for k in Lst:

    a, b, c = k
    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Not sure what this solves. OP wants different "slices" assigned to different variables.