# Linking variables from different functions to print them

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm learning about functions at the moment. I have created a simple program that asks the user for some information and then prints it. However, I'm having problems linking the `return` variables from one function to the `print()` statements in the other function.
This is what I have so far:

```
def ask_data():
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    last_name = input("What's your last name?: ")
    age = input("how old are you?: ")
    return(name, last_name, age)

def print_data(data):
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")

def main():
    data = ask_data()
    print_data(data)

main()
```

My problem is that I'm able to enter all the information, meaning that `ask_data()` is working. However, when `print_data()` is called, I get an error saying the variables `name`, `last_name`, and `age` couldn't be found. How can I link both functions, if that's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The thing to remember is in your `main` function, the variable `data` refers to a tuple, so within `print_data` you actually cannot refer to `name`, `last_name`, and `age` directly. You must first "unpack" the values in the tuple like so:

```
def print_data(data):
    name, last_name, age = data
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")
```

The thing to remember is variables declared in a function stay in that function. The variable `name` inside of `ask_data` stays in `ask_data`. You were correct to wrap up all the values in a tuple and return that, then pass that tuple to `print_data` (that's good!) but `print_data` doesn't know the original names of those values. You have to make *new* variables inside of `print_data`, because the names of local variables are "private" to each function that defines them.

Answer (score 0):

because your variables in `data` and function `def print_data()` does not know about: *name*, *last_name* and *age*.

Example:

```
def print_data(data):
    print("Your name is ", data[0], data[1])
    print("and you are ", data[2], "years old")
```

Where data[0] it is youre *name*, data[1] is *last_name* and last var *age* in data[2].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the error `NameError: name 'name' is not defined` when you run your script. This is because you need to perform **tuple unpacking**. You can find great examples in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking).

To make your script work, you can perform the unpacking at any stage. The simplest modification would be as follow:

```
def ask_data():
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    last_name = input("What's your last name?: ")
    age = input("how old are you?: ")
    return(name, last_name, age)

def print_data(data):
    # This will unpack 'data' and make those variables available
    name, last_name, age = data
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")

def main():
    data = ask_data()
    print_data(data)

main()
```

One other approach, which produces the exact same result, would be as follow:

```
def ask_data():
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    last_name = input("What's your last name?: ")
    age = input("how old are you?: ")
    return(name, last_name, age)

def print_data(name, last_name, age):  # Giving the function new parameters
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")

def main():
    name, last_name, age = ask_data()  # Unpacking outside the function
    print_data(name, last_name, age)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments unpacking in your function. Have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/).

You would obtain something like this:

```
def print_data(name, last_name, age):
    ...

def main():
    data = ask_data()
    print_data(*data)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use the global statement

```
def ask_data():
    global name, last_name, age
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    last_name = input("What's your last name?: ")
    age = input("how old are you?: ")
    return(name, last_name, age)

def print_data(data):
    global name, last_name, age
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")

def main():
    global name, last_name, age
    data = ask_data()
    print_data(data)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ask_data():
    return name, last_name, age
name = input("What's your name?: ")           # i indented your variable to the same line as the funtion "ask_data" 
last_name = input("What's your last name?: ") #reason: so that any of your funtion (e.g. print_data) below can access them
age = input("how old are you?: ")             # you can bring these variable above "def ask_data" if you want.

def print_data(data):                         # in this program you don't need the 1 argument "data". "print_data()" is enough
    print("Your name is ", name, last_name)  # reason: data is not defined, 
    print("and you are ", age, "years old")

def main():
    ask_data()
    print_data("data") # because the word data has not been define, (your can only use it as a string to call print_data
                     # like this print_data("data"). if it was defined, then you can call it as a variable without " ".

main()


my input:
       What's your name?: Simon
       What's your last name?: cigar
       how old are you?: 35

output:
       Your name is  Simon cigar
       and you are  35 years old
```