# Unpacking: [x,y], (x,y), x,y - what is the difference?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

What is the difference in Python between unpacking a function call with `[]`, with `()` or with nothing?

```py
def f():
    return 0, 1

a, b = f() # 1
[a, b] = f() # 2
(a, b) = f() # 3
```

Comment: There is no difference at all.  If you need more convincing, use the `dis` module to disassemble functions containing each version, and observe that their bytecode is identical.

Comment: the only sifference you would ever find is if you called type( thing ).__name__

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate, definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking

Comment: @reece There's nothing to call `type` on, though; the brackets are purely syntactic here. `[a, b] = f()` does not create a list of any kind here.

Comment: For this case, all are redundant. But parentheses can be useful for unpacking nested things: `a, (b, c) = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]` leads to `a = [0, 1]`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch that's a good point! but again, `a, [b, c] = ...` will give the same result...

Comment: I think that's a different issue, though. (I debated removing it from "my" answer, but I did make it a community wiki, and it's not *wrong*, so... :) )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no difference. Regardless of what kind of *syntactic* sequence you use, the same byte code is generated.

```
>>> def f():
...   return 0, 1
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('[a,b] = f()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('(a,b) = f()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('a, b = f()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

In every case, you simply call `f`, then use `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` to produce the values to assign to `a` and `b`.

---

Even if you want to argue that byte code is an implementation detail of CPython, the definition of a chained assignment is *not*. Given

```
x = [a, b] = f()
```

the meaning is the same as

```
tmp = f()
x = tmp
[a, b] = tmp
```

`x` is assigned the result of `f()` (a tuple), not the "list" `[a, b]`.

---

Finally, here is the grammar for an assignment statement:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

Arguably, the `"[" [target_list] "]"` could and should have been removed in Python 3. Such a breaking change would be difficult to implement now, given the stated preference to avoid any future changes to Python on the scale of the 2-to-3 transition.

Comment: Also, I *believe* the definition of the assignment operator `:=` precludes any tricks like `(x := [a,b]) = f()`. (That, at least, is definitely a syntax error.)

Answer (score 8):

As the other answer has explained, there is no semantic difference. The only reason to prefer one form over another is visual clarity; `x, y = f()` is usually neater, but something like `[(id,)] = do_sql_query()` may sometimes be written to indicate that the result is expected to be a list containing a tuple. The assignment target `[(id,)]` is semantically equivalent to `(id,),` but it communicates something more to the human reader.