# Translating a string to pig latin

Tags: python, string

So I recently came to know about the asterisk function in Python which is used to unpack the values. I tried to implement it in my code for the given question below. But unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solution import *
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 2
    return *[x[1:]+x[0]+'ay' for x in text.split()]
           ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

**Q.Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add "ay" to the end of the word. Leave punctuation marks untouched.**

**Examples**

```
pig_it('Pig latin is cool') # igPay atinlay siay oolcay
pig_it('Hello world !')     # elloHay orldway !
```

My Code:

```
def pig_it(text):
    return *[x[1:]+x[0]+'ay' for x in text.split()]
```

Comment: What do you expect the `*` to do here?

Comment: I am expecting a string containing the elements in the list. It should be same as the output given by: ' '.join([x[1:]+x[0]+'ay' for x in text.split()])

Comment: That is not a function, it is part of the language syntax, and what it means depends on context, but it isn't a function (although sometimes an operator)

Comment: If a=[1,2,3,4]. Then print(*a) gives '1 2 3 4' right?

Comment: It is totally unclear *waht* you expect `*` to do in `return *some_list`

Comment: Yes * is a part of the syntax. So why exactly isn't it not working here? Could you please explain.

Comment: @Hrishi that's because `*` *unpacks an interable as the positional arguments to a function call, in this case `print`*, it has nothing to do with `''.join`

Comment: What I am expecting is the output (given as a comment) beside the examples

Comment: @Hrishi the *problem* is that `return *whatever` **doesn't make sense**. It isn't valid syntax, as the error states. You seem to misunderstand what `*` is doing in `print(*whatever)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So brother can you tell me if I am correct about the concept. * combines the elements in a given lists into a string where each of the elements is seperated by a space. Like, arr = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday'] and if we do print (*arr) we get "sunday monday tuesday wednesday". Is it correct? I tried the same logic here except that I returned it.

Comment: What is your source for claiming *"\* combines the elements in a given lists into a string"*? It doesn't. `print` can take a variable number of arguments, and `*` spreads (spashes, unpacks, ...) values to become multiple arguments. There is no string conversion nor concatenation happening.

Comment: @Hrishi "* combines the elements in a given lists into a string where each of the elements is seperated by a space" That is *totally wrong*. This is what I'm telling you, you are misunderstanding what is happening. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking)

Comment: Thank you trincot & juanpa.arrivillaga.                        
 def pig_it(text):
    a=[x[1:]+x[0]+'ay' for x in text.split()]
    print(*a)
print(pig_it('Pig latin is cool'))    
''' Output
igPay atinlay siay oolcay
None
'''
This code kinda made me misunderstand the whole concept. When I saw this I thought the same statement inside the print could be used inside a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) or similar, and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
return ' '.join(x[1:] + x[0] + 'ay' if x.isalpha() else x for x in text.split())
```

This does not check for punctuation attached to a word.

Star expansion, or splat, is totally irrelevant in this case. It deals the elements of an iterable into a sequence or argument list. Since you don't really have a sequence or argument list anywere, you don't need or want splat.