# Why is Python using old value of a variable? How to achieve the same using JavaScript?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code which is for a LeetCode problem.

```
class Solution:
    def isRobotBounded(instructions: str) -> bool:
        dirX, dirY = 0, 1
        x, y = 0, 0

        for d in instructions:
            if d == "G":
                x, y = x + dirX, y + dirY
            elif d == "L":
                dirX, dirY = -1*dirY, dirX
            else:
                dirX, dirY = dirY, -1*dirX

        return (x, y) == (0, 0) or (dirX, dirY) != (0, 1)
    print(isRobotBounded('GGLLGG'))
```

Now, in `d == "L"`, why is `dirX` used as `0` to calculate the value of `dirY`? In JavaScript, `dirX` would be calculated (`-1*dirY`) and then used to calculate `dirY`.

What am I missing here regarding Python? It looks like Python is using the initial values of the variables. What is this behavior called? And how to replicate it in JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking

Comment: The right side of the assignment is evaluated completely before the variables on the left are assigned.

Comment: Python evaluates the *whole* expression on the right before doing the assignment part of that statement.  That is why `a,b=b,a` can be used to swap `a` & `b`.

Comment: How do I do the same in JavaScript?

Comment: Use destructuring: `[dirX, dirY] = [-1*dirY, dirX];`

Comment: @Barmar would you like to put both your comments in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No, this has been answered in numerous other questions.